# How can I serialize a HtmlNode and all its descendants back to HTML

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using Html Agility Pack to extract information from a HTML source.

I find a HtmlHode like this:

```
doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//div[@id='toc']"]
```

My question is is there a way for me to serialize the HtmlNode and all its descendants back to HTML string?

And if there is a way to output the TEXT node descendants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the HTML markup from `OuterHtml` property :

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//div[@id='toc']");
foreach(HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    string html = node.OuterHtml;
    .....
}
```

Regarding the last question, it isn't very clear to me what you meant by *outputting the text node descendants*. If you meant something like what XPath's `string()` function does (returning concatenated string of all text node descendants), you can try `InnerText` property (please clarify if turn out this isn't the functionality you're after). <s>I'm afraid there is no built in method to do that in the library. You need to write your own method/codes to achieve that.</s>